# Git listing unchaned content files when extracting backup to directory

Tags: git

My git status shows files that have the same content as changed.
I extracted my online website files to my local directory to do a git comparrison of the all the differences between lokal and online files. Just a few files are editted and it shows almost all the files are changed.

I set the configs below but nothing changed.

```
git config core.filemode false   
git config --global core.filemode false
```

Comment: have you ruled out end of line issues ? what does `git diff` show you in a terminal ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes I have. I changed it using * text=off in .gitattributes

Comment: @Ehsan: I don't know what you think `text=off` does, but [it's not documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) and I suspect that this is a mistake that somehow spread throughout the internet.